# Spring MVC returning wrong Http Status Code

Tags: java, spring, exception

Why does my web app return 200 when an exception is thrown? Even though I get the correct response body for an error.

A sample response would be:

```
Status Code = 200
Body: { "error": "User does not exist" }
```

My code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{userId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void updateUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
        @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, String> fields)
        throws UserNotFoundException {
    // code that leads to the exception being thrown
}

@ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public ErrorDto userNotFound() {
    return new ErrorDto("User does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was not in the controller but in my `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. When I was forwarding requests to my controller, I was using `RequestDispatcher.include()` instead `RequestDispatcher.dispatcher()` because I thought it was the solution to an earlier problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding the `HttpServletResponse` as a method argument and setting the response code there:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorDto userNotFound(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    return new ErrorDto("User does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Strange - I used it yesterday in my own project, and it was setting the status correctly.